# PHP: Unable to redirect to another page under a condition

Tags: php

I'm having troubles in using a redirect in a PHP page. Basically, I'm using the following function to redirect:

```
function redirect($url) {
    ob_start();
    header('Location: '.$url);
    ob_end_flush();
    die();
}
```

Then, at the beginning of the PHP page, I'm checking for a var value. If that's over a threshold, I redirect to another page:

```
<?php 
. . .
if (var >= 100) {
   redirect('error1.html');
}
?>  
<html>
 <body>
  <!-- HTML page here -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Although the var is over 100 (it is printed on the screen), no redirect takes place. Any idea why? Is it because there's HTML content included in the page?

Comment: Where is your 'redirect' function defined?

Comment: Note that `var` is different than `$var`. Which one do you really use? Please try `var_dump(var);` (in case you use `var`) to see what is this value.

Comment: You must not send anything to the browser before you do the redirection with header(). If you need that, you can use ob_start() at the beggining of your script, or at least before any output is send, and do ob_end_flush() at the end. Those functions are unuseful the way you're using them inside redirect(9 function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use "if (var...)" cause **var** is a protected term.

I don't know if is this an example but the correct way to do what you like, should be:

```
    function redirect( $code, $url ) {

        // Test code
        if( $code >= 100 ){
          
          // If you will redirect you don't need OB function
          // ob_start(); ** removed
          
          // Redirect
          header('Location: '.$url);
          
          // ob_end_flush(); ** removed
          exit(); // better use function exit then die
        
        } // end if test code
    }

    ...

    <?PHP 
    
        redirect( $code, 'error1.html');
    ?>
´´´

Hope help you ! ;)
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked! honestly I didn't use "var" as variable. I've just created a simple snippet. Nevertheless it worked with your help.

Comment: Perfect. Happy to help you :)